# JBoss Server not running in Virtualbox Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: jboss, virtualbox, ubuntu

I tried to install everything for developing a Maven-Application in a VM in VirtualBox with Kubuntu 14.04. I have installed the EXACT same software on my desktop PC, also on Kubuntu 14.04 and it works perfectly. In the VM the JBoss-starting process stops after the "JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting"-message.

Here is the content of boot.log:

```
01:39:45,816 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
01:39:46,337 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
01:39:46,404 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
01:39:46,406 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /usr/local/share/jboss/jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_05-b13
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_05
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.5-b02
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.bind.address = localhost
    jboss.bind.address.management = localhost
    jboss.home.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss
    jboss.host.name = igor-virtualbox
    jboss.modules.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = igor-virtualbox
    jboss.qualified.host.name = igor-virtualbox
    jboss.server.base.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/data/content
    jboss.server.log.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/log
    jboss.server.name = igor-virtualbox
    jboss.server.temp.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = /usr/local/share/jboss/modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/log/boot.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.13.0-24-generic
    path.separator = :
    program.name = JBossTools: JBoss AS 7.1
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/resources.jar:/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/rt.jar:/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/jce.jar:/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = org.jboss.modules.Main -mp /usr/local/share/jboss/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/share/jboss/standalone
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
    user.country = US
    user.dir = /usr/local/share/jboss/bin
    user.home = /home/igor
    user.language = en
    user.name = igor
    user.timezone = Europe/Berlin
01:39:46,467 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss AS 7.1 -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/share/jboss -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Can someone give me a hint, why this happens in the VM? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing Java jdk1.7.0_60 instead of 1.8.0_05. As strange, as it sounds, but it runs with 1.8.0 on my desktop PC.

If someone can explain me, why this happens, please do :)